# Laravel Session Limit

Tags: laravel, session

How do you get session items with limits?

I have cart which is storing items in session and I want to show only latest 2 items that added to session, how do i do that?

[image: usage sample]

I'm using this in my composer view, here is my code

```
//cart products
      View::composer('*', function ($view) {
        $user = Auth()->user();
        if (!Session::has('cart')) {
          return view('frontend.cart');
        }
        $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
        $total = $cart->totalPrice;
        $view->with('products', $cart->items, 'totalPrice', $cart->totalPrice, 'user', $user, 'total', $total);
      });
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do this by using `put` :

```
Session::put('sess_cart', $request->input('cart'));
```